# Executing external program in Java - huge CPU load

Tags: java

I have this code in my program:

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

        builder.directory(new File(Vars.pathToForFfmpegBinDir));

        final Process process = builder.start();

        InputStream is = process.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("!!! "+line);
        }
```

Because external program get many output info, it's loaded 100 % of one CPU core per `while` cycle.

I have try another version of this code:

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectError(new File(pathToForModerationDir+"/1err.log"));
        builder.redirectOutput(new File(pathToForModerationDir+"/1inp.log"));
        builder.directory(new File(Vars.pathToForFfmpegBinDir));

        final Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
```

But it is loaded 100 % of one CPU core per Process.

How I can reduce CPU load in this code?

Comment: If you execute the external command from a terminal, you don't have the CPU load issue?

Comment: The part in your program that reads: "Processing images" doesn't bode well for your CPU load issue

Comment: No, in cmd program execute very well. CMD usage ~0.5%...

Comment: If output and error are truly high volume, you should not force the Java parent to catch it all and write it to some file or standard output. I suppose `cmd` is capable of redirection, so simply modify the `command` by adding suitable redirections. - If you want to remain with your approach: note that it is a good idea for the returned input stream(s) to be buffered.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing.  Either your JVM has a bug, the code you are running is different to what you think it is, or your calling program is doing something really unusual.  Try testing this with a trivial program like `sleep 60000` to provide to yourself this doesn't have to use much CPU at all.

Comment: Use blocking buffered IO and add timed wait(ms) to the body of your loop

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, I tried to find it on `top` but it uses less than 0.1% of CPU and doesn't appear in my top 20 processes for my user id.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 1; date; done");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
final Process process = builder.start();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
        System.out.println("!!! " + line);
}
```